# Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ such that $\int_0^x f = \int_x^1 f$, what is $f$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1]$, and suppose that for all $x$, $0<x<1$,
>
> $\int_0^x f = \int_x^1 f$
>
> Can you determine $f$?

I've argued the following:

Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, it follows that $f$ has an antiderivative $F$ on $I=[0,1]$.

Evaluating both sides of the equation we get

$F(x)-F(0) = F(1)-F(x)$=

$2F(x) = F(1) + F(0)$

$F(x) = \frac{F(1) + F(0)}{2}$

Taking the derivative of both sides we get

$F'(x) = f(x) = \frac{F'(1) + F'(0)}{2} = 0$ since $F(1) + F(0)$ is a constant.

I'm not sure if I'm going about this problem correctly.

Comment: Aside from the "since $F(1) + F(0)$ missing a conclusion, yes this is correct. This is a ridiculously strong assumption: It says that no matter how you split the interval $[0, 1]$ into two subintervals, the mass that $f$ carries on each one is the same. That's too strong for any non-zero function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your method is generally correct, but I think this problem is easier than you think. We have:

$$\int_0^x f(t)dt=\int_x^1 f(t)dt=-\int_1^x f(t)dt$$

Use the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) to take the derivative of both sides:

$$f(x)=-f(x)\rightarrow 2f(x)=0\rightarrow f(x)=0$$

Thus, $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in [0, 1]$.

Comment: Beat me to it by 2 minutes. +1

Answer (score 7):

The use of the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) makes the solution simpler. Since the two functions $x\mapsto\int_0^x f$ and $x\mapsto\int_x^1 f$ are identical on the interval $(0,1)$, it follows that their derivatives are also equal: $$f(x)=-f(x)\quad\text{for every $x\in(0,1)$.}$$ Hence, $f(x)=0$ for every $x\in(0,1)$ and, by continuity, also for the endpoints $x=0$ and $x=1$.